# Como faço para atualizar um botão quando de um evento externo?

Tags: python, tkinter

Fiz um pequeno aplicativo onde se comunica com uma unidade externa consultando algumas variáveis booleanas. Dependendo do status destas variáveis, é colocado um botão na tela e incluído uma figura neste indicando o status desta unidade. Ex.:

```
if Status_Botão_Aberto_A: 
    Photo_A = Photo_Aberto #carrega a figura referente ao status da unidade
Mais adiante: 
    A = Button(command=lambda : Comando(True, False, 1.Status_Botao_Aberto_A, Status_Botao_Fechado_A))
    A.place(x=76, y=87)m #posição do Botão
    A.config(imagem=Photo_A. width="42", height="42")
    A=Button(root)
```

Minha duvida é que para atualizar estes botões, que são quatro, tenho que comunicar com cada uma das unidade para testar as variáveis de estado. para isso, tive que colocar antes de `root.mainloop` o comando `root.after(1000, Loop_interface)`, onde a cada segundo chama o função principal.

Comment: sim, e qual problema você está tendo? 
Chamar o método `.after` é de fato a forma correta de fazer isso - o seu loop, em vez de ficar num while, deve executar apenas uma vez, checando os dispositvos, e chamar novamente o `root.after(...)`

Comment: Boa tarde e obrigado pelo esclarecimento. Não tinha achado nenhum exemplo de código parecido com o que me propus a fazer. Minha dúvida era de que se usar .after não estaria forçando o código a executar de maneira inadvertida pelo fato de haver o método .mainloop.